# How to return to my app in facebook registration social plugin in android phonegap project?

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I have successfully implemented facebook connect plugin in android phonegap project with help of [phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect](https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/).

Also successfully implemented the  facebook registration social plugin using iframe, first example shown in above facebook url.
Then i came up with :-  [image with output](http://i774.photobucket.com/albums/yy29/rajugotame/Screen-Shot-2012-07-30-at-121458-PM.png)
When i click the register button, it goes out of my app and goes to  mobile default browser and comes up with undo and continue button, when i click continue button nothing happens.

What i want is that  want to return to my app after clicking continue button in browser.How can i do this ?

Also is it possible to open inside my app after clicking register button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that much about the Android browser, but I think you could just hook the click to the registration iframe and then close it when you detect a navigation event.

that all said, this is a really complex way to do this -- I would just have simple native registration form.

Comment: you mean i shouldn't use phonegap for this project ?

Answer (score 0):

Use childbrowser when going to the facebook page